# backup data sets in SAS

Tags: sas

I wrote this programm  to back up my data set in a particualr library. Now I want to modify this program in such a way that   if run a program again only those data sets will backup which are modified over a two weeks.

proc sql;
    select distinct memname 
    into: ord_int_list separated by ' '
    from sashelp.vcolumn
    where libname = "space"
    order by memname;
quit;

%let ord_int_n = &sqlobs;

%macro backup();

```
%do i = 1 %to &ord_int_n;
    %let spc = %scan(&ord_int_list, &i);

    data libname.&spc. (compress = CHAR);
        set ord_int.&spc.;
    run;

%end;
```

%mend;

%backup();

Comment: Please clarify what your actual question is.  As it is asked, there isn't really a question here, and the only thing I could see as a question is too long for this format.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like the code below.

- Use dictionary.tables with filter on MODATE (modification date)
- PROC COPY should be better than datastep to preserve exact properties, also allows to keep indexes, constraints...

data *null*;

```
format backup_after datetime.;
backup_after =dhms(today() - 14, 0,0,0); /* 14 days back */

call symputx('backup_after', catt('"', put(backup_after, datetime. -L), '"DT'));
run;

%put &backup_after;

proc sql; 
    select memname into: backup_list separated by ' ' from dictionary.tables
    where libname = "space" 
        and modate >= &backup_after
order by memname;
quit;

proc copy in=space out=backup clone datecopy index=yes constraint=yes;
select &backup_list;
run;
```

Comment: This macro is realy realy helpfull in backing up the data sets. With some modification you can get amazing results per business requirment.